# VS2013 WPF designer not responding after even simple save

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my WPF application, whenever I make some changes to XAML, either XAML for controls or resource, after I click save, it takes long time, I mean the VS freezes for really long time, during which both the VS window and task manager show "Not Responding". "Clean solution" also makes it not responding for long time. It can't be that I am running out of memory since I have 24GB RAM and in the Task Manager it says currently only 35% of the memory is being used.

I suspect it has something to do with initializing the design-time `DataContext` for my `UserControl`. Because when I only have non-UI files opened I never have this problem. But the worst thing about this problem is I don't even know where to begin to solve it. Can anybody help me!

Comment: you may have a look on installed extensions, may there is one bothering you.

Comment: @pushpraj But how? Is there any tracing tool to see what piece of SW/extension which is taking long time? Or Do I have to uninstall/install the extension one-by-one?

Comment: @tete you can 'deactivate' the plug ins one by one. It should be a little faster than actually deinstalling them.

Comment: I suspect that your viewModel which is set as `DataContext` is getting data using Background worker or other way that is making it difficult for designer to cope. If you want make the constructor empty and see if that works, and if you need display data use `FallbackValue` to display mock values. Alternatively use designdata.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I rarely (but not never) assign the `DataContext` in the code-behind of `View` (currently things are a bit mess in the design of `ViewModel` and wiring of it to `View`. So I was wondering if there is any routine to see what's happening in Designer so I can really narrow it down

Comment: Sorry I don't know about that, but I've heard about `ShadowCache` for VS and sometimes that is causing Designer time issues,  search online for that. I meant assigning DataContext in `xaml` of your view. this way and use `DesignData` I used it for my last project and it's great during design time, defo recomended.

Comment: @XAMlMAX thanks, I'll look into that tomorrow. But I mean I seldom assign the `DataContext` in the constructors of `View` (in the constructor there is normally only `InitializeComponent`, I don't know if that is what you mean by "make the constructor empty"). So the designer normally doesn't need to get/initialize any data for the `View`. But I do have some `View` whose `DataContext` is assigned in constructor. It would be exhausting to check them one by one and that's why I hope there is a tracking tool to help me

Comment: Hi, I meant the `ViewModel`'s `Constructor` to be empty, cause every time you make a change the designer will try to re-evaluate the `DataContext` and if you have so many `ViewModel`s in your `Views` `Constructor`s it might be causing the delay. I found that if my `VM`'s `Constructor` has some tasks to do, it will affect the performance. HTH